# How to fetch and populate data from firebase collections in react correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So i have component called Agents, that's by it's nature is table with rows that contain data about agents.

I want to get full data about agents from firestore, populate it with data from another collection in firestore, and then render it to the screen.

Here is working piece of code, but i have some questions:

1. Why now i have render with some delay? (First i have spinner about loading - it's okay, i expect it, but then spinner hides and i see 1 agent in table for 0.5s, and then i see all data. I want to see all data after spinner gone. What is the problem of my code?
2. How to populate data. Maybe there is another way to do that, or maybe there is another good practice, cause i think my "componentDidMount" is horrible, the solutions that i use are not common i guess.

So for 2 question i will describe what i want:

In users collection i have documents, they are objects, that have property called - **profile**. That property contains ID of document from collection called **roles**! I want to get that data by that document id. That's why my componendDidMount is async, cause i want to wait till i get data from roles collection by id of document.

Help me please optimise my code )

```
class Agents extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    agents: [],
    showOptionsFor: null
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .orderBy('lastName')
      .onSnapshot(async snapshot => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges()

        let agents = this.state.agents
        for (const change of changes) {
          const agent = {
              id: change.doc.id,
              ...change.doc.data()
            }

          if (change.type === 'added' || change.type === 'modified') {
            await firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection('roles')
              .doc(change.doc.data().profile).get().then( response => {
                agent['role'] = response.data().profile
                agents.push(agent)
                }
              )
          }

          if (change.type === 'modified') {
            const newAgentsArray = agents.filter(element => {
              return element.id !== change.doc.id
            })
            agents = newAgentsArray

            agents.push(agent)
          }
      }

      this.setState({
        agents: agents,
        isLoading: false
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: It's hard for us to speculate on the UI of your app. But if you log timestamps in your `componentDidMount`, I'd expect the `onSnapshot` callback to fire after some delay (that mostly depends on your network connection, and the amount of data you request), and then each of the `get()` calls to go at a fairly standard pace. If you put those log statements in and share their output, it might be easier to spot what's going on.

Comment: thx for reply. I have already saw, that it depends of internet connection. Some tests showed different results of getting data, so i think question 1 is not so important as question 2 for me)